# null checks after json.decode

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to quickly check for null entries in decoded JSON object?

For example:

```
final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
```

this returns the following:

```
responseJson['result']['mydata']['account'] = 'Joe Doe';
```

In order to check if 'mydata' part is not null, I have to do the following:

```
if(responseJson != null)
        {
           if(responseJson['result'] != null)
              {

                 if(responseJson['result']['mydata'] != null)
...
```

which is really ugly. How to do it this way:

```
if((responseJson != null) && (responseJson['result'] != null) && (responseJson['result']['mydata'] != null))
{
}
```

In Dart this gives exception in case some of the middle item is null (i.e. ['result']).

There are null aware operators like:

```
obj?.method()
```

but how to use them with decoded JSON map object?

Comment: What exception do you get in the 2nd example? Dart should short-circuit and not evaluate the following `&& ...` expression if the previous failed.

Comment: I expected the same, but it's not the case. It does not short-circuit in this case like other languages. In case ['result'] is null, it will complain about requesting ['mydata'] from null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set a value like in

```
responseJson['result']['mydata']['account'] = 'Joe Doe';
```

this might work for you

```
data.putIfAbsent('result', () => {})
    .putIfAbsent('mydata', () => {})
    .putIfAbsent('account', () => 'John Doe');
```

For reading you can use

```
  if(data.containsKey('result') && data['result'].containsKey('mydata')) {
    data['result']['mydata']['account'] = 'Joe Doe';
  } else {
    print('empty');
  }
```

Comment: Maybe add a comment that this doesn't work if the entry is present with an explicit value of `null` (but then, it doesn't work if the value is a string either).

Comment: Thank you, I think containsKey() is what I need. It "short-circuit" properly compared to just (somevar['key'] != null)

Answer (score 5):

What you should do instead of directly using the JSON object is to convert it to a Dart class. Then use null aware operator.

```
final response = new Response.fromJSON(json.decode(''));

if (response?.result?.myData != null) {

}
```

You can generate `fromJSON` class constructors using `json_serializable` or `built_value`.

Or you can write them manually :

```
class Data {
  String account;

  Data.fromJSON(Map json) {
    if (json.containsKey('myData')) {
      account = json['myData'];
    }
  }
}

class Result {
  Data myData;

  Result({this.myData});

  Result.fromJSON(Map json) {
    if (json.containsKey('myData')) {
      myData = json['myData'];
    }
  }
}

class Response {
  Result result;

  Response({this.result});

  Response.fromJSON(Map json) {
    if (json.containsKey('result')) {
      result = json['result'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will try to just use "if(data.containsKey('result') && data['result'].containsKey('mydata'))" for simplicity.